# fit a large div to a small div and keep ratio: absolute elements

Tags: javascript, php, css

This issue is giving me a nightmare and is stalling a project. I a have a div that is `480px by 280px` with absolutely positioned elements. text, images with different sizes. I want to shrink the div to fit a mobile device maybe `300px by 180px`. I have tried css media queries but font sizes, element positions and image dimensions remain the same, only the canvas changes size.

My Code :

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
 $('#btn').click(function()
     {
             var div=$('#bigcard').html();
             $('#smallcard').html(div);
              }
              );

  }); 
} 

#bigcard
{
width:500px;
height:300px;
border-width:2px;
border-color:black;
border:1px solid black;
background:orange;

}
#smallcard
{
 width:200px;
 height:130px;
 background:pink;
 border:1px solid black;
}

 Big Div
<div id="bigcard">
<span style="position:absolute;font-size:15px;color:green;font-family:fantacy:margin-top:20px;margin-left:40px;">Some user generated text</span> 
<span style="font-size:35px;color:black;font-family:tahoma;margin-top:200px;margin-left:90px;font-weight:bold;position:absolute;">Foo Foo</span> 
 <img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/Y/f/v/m/p/3/flying-bird-md.png" id="image1" style="margin-top:50px;margin-left:100px;width:80px;"/>
 <img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/Y/f/v/m/p/3/flying-bird-md.png" id="image1" style="margin-top:100px;margin-left:130px;width:50px;"/>
 </div>


Small div
<div id="smallcard">  </div>
<a href="#" id="btn">Click here</a>
```

Please check the fiddle-> http://jsfiddle.net/gscq1jqw/1/

I want help adding the large div to the small div by scalling down without losing any pixel. Please ask any clarification. My website is http://thecardguys.co.ke/ and I am building a mobile version

Comment: Nothing to do with php

Comment: Sure. I am desperate.

Comment: Its because I had tried to loop through html data that creates the div and change every element's size to a lower value. dump move. You have an idea @Epodax

Comment: There are no media queries in your fiddle.

Comment: It didnt have even the slightest effect @timo Thats why I didnt include it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated:**

Bit of trial and error landed us with css transformation as the solution

```
$('#bigcard').css({'transform': 'scale(0.5)'});
```

Where, of course, you're probably better off putting that in a function that accepts an element & ratio, rather than hard coded.

**Original:**

Well... Putting a div inside another div isn't exactly emulating a screensize change. And you're setting the birds position on "Margin-top:200px" which means it's always going to be positioned 200px from the top. All your elements are positioned based on pxls from the side, which they'll be no matter the screensize or whatever div element they belong to.

Consider using percentage for positioning instead. For example, setting the bird to 10% width and height, and positioned 10% from the left. That scales properly.

```
.bigBird{
    width:10%;
    position:absolute; 
    top:50%;
    left:20%;
}
```

Made a fiddle for you. Didn't put too much time into making the fiddle perfect, but it should give you the general idea. Assuming I understood what you wanted to do correctly that is
https://jsfiddle.net/gscq1jqw/2/
(Also I may or may not have put padding on the divs for no apparent reason. You can consider it an easteregg)

Comment: Hi @Jonas, thanks for the advice and I totally get the point. The fiddle is addressing my first issue. But my application uses absolute positioning to align elements . The elements are added dynamically and so u really can align them specifically please visit here>> http://thecardguys.co.ke/customize_design.php?card=beautiful_business_cards_for_pet_stores,_farms_and&cid=115&step=2   and see exactly my point.

Comment: So when adding new elements , I am using jquery draggable and resizable which places elements in absolute positions. I want to be able to shrink the generated html card to fit a smaller editor. Hope you get my point. And hope you have more ideas for me

Comment: Well, you could try iterating through the child elements and adjusting their positioning/width based on the size change? How exactly do you want it to work though; fully responsive when you resize the screensize, or just adjusted on startup based on the window?

Comment: I dont want it to be responsive, I just want it smaller to a specific size. Seems I will have to do it the hard way. Just inform me if you get an idea. Thanks

Comment: What about using css transform to scale it then? $('#bigcard').css({'transform': 'scale(0.5)'}); will resize it and its content. No idea how that interacts with jQuery UI draggable though

Comment: Your Idea worked exacty the way I needed!!!!  @jonasR, Please post it as an answer I accept it for future programmers. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#bigcard').css({'transform': 'scale(0.5)'});
```

Solution given by JonasR works for my case